# How rotate a 3D cube at its center XNA?

Tags: xna, c#, models, rotation, transformation

I try to rotate a 3D cube on itself from its center, not the edge.
Here is my code used.

```
public rotatemyCube()
{
    ...
    Matrix newTransform = Matrix.CreateScale(scale) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotationLoot) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(translation);
    my3Dcube.Transform = newTransform;
    ....


public void updateRotateCube()
{
    rotationLoot += 0.01f;
}
```

My cube rotate fine, but not from the center. Here is a schematic that explains my problem.
[image]

And i need this:
[image]

Comment: The order of your matrix multiplications matters. Translate first.

Comment: I tried but it is not better damage...

Comment: Is my3Dcube your own 3D model (created in an external tool)? Your vertices might be in the 0-1 range instead of -.5-.5 range. So like Byte56 said, translate your Cube so that the center is at 0,0. before your rotate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to rotate an object around.Center must be at the point(0,0,0)
To achieve that simply Translate the object to point(0,0,0) Rotate and Translate back

```
example:
Translate(0,0,-1)
Rotate(90)
Translate(0,0,1)
```

Comment: i have try this :var rotationCenter = new Vector3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);

                        Matrix transformation = Matrix.CreateTranslation(translation - rotationCenter)
                            * Matrix.CreateScale(scale)
                            * Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotationLoot)
                            * Matrix.CreateTranslation(translation + rotationCenter)
                            ;
 but not work..

Comment: Try this -> Matrix.CreateTranslation(-rotationCenter) * Matrix.CreateScale(scale) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotationLoot) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(translation)